# How to test custom React-query hook that is based on Firebase methods?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, testing, jestjs, react-query

I came across react-query-firebase which are hooks that are built on React-query for firebase.

I also found library called mock service worker https://mswjs.io/ however it is based on REST and GraphQL.

Here is an example code how I would use these hooks:

```
import React from "react";
import { useFirestoreDocument } from "@react-query-firebase/firestore";
import {
  doc
} from "firebase/firestore";
import { firestore } from "../firebase";

function GetUser() {
  const id = "pW5CizOJOpXezr5lGGshDmKdVpP3";
  const ref = doc(firestore, "users", id);
  const user = useFirestoreDocument(["users", id], ref);

  return (
    <div>
      {user.isLoading && <div>Loading...</div>}
      {user.data && <div>{user.data.data()?.name}</div>}
    </div>
  );
}

export default GetUser;
```

I am new to testing and I have no idea how would I have to execute this test, since I am mocking requests can I use random url anyways or does it have to be firebase related methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[react-query-firebase](https://github.com/invertase/react-query-firebase) library is an abstraction over Firebase that encapsulates resource paths (it's an SDK, I believe). Since the paths (URLs) are abstracted from, you have at least two options for how to mock requests issued by such libraries.

### Option 1: Use explicit paths

Although the exact resource paths are hidden away, *requests still reference existing absolute paths*. You can observe those in the "Network" tab of your browser or by enabling a simple request introspection with `msw`:

```js
// my.test.js
import { setupServer } from 'msw/node'

const server = setupServer(/* no handlers */)

beforeAll(() => server.listen())
afterAll(() => server.close())
```

> Since we're using `setupServer` with no handlers, all requests that happen in `my.test.js` will be printed as warnings to `stderr`. You can observe those warnings to see what resource paths your SDK requests.

The benefit of using an SDK is that it guarantees you a certain resource path structure. Most likely, you will be able to replicate that structure in your mocks:

```js
// src/mocks.js
import { rest } from 'msw'

export const handlers = [
  rest.get('https://some-resource.:checksum.firebase.app/path', (req, res, ctx) => res(ctx.text('hello)))
]
```

> Utilize dynamic path segments like `:checksum` to match a broader range of paths.

The downside of this approach is that your mock definition becomes dependent on the SDK internal details (resource paths). Any updates to the SDK may break your mocks, since they may update the path structure internally without denoting it as a breaking change (abstracted paths are not public API).

### Option 2: Spy on the SDK

Alternatively, you can spy on the SDK you're using. An example of such a spy would be using `jest.spyOn` on the `react-query-firebase` directly:

```js
// my.test.js
import * as reactQueryFirebase from 'react-query-firebase'

it('creates a user', () => {
  jest.spyOn(reactQueryFirebase, 'SOME_METHOD_NAME')
    .mockReturnValue(/* mock */)
})
```

The downside of this method is that you're stubbing the functions from a third-party library, which means your code under test never calls those functions. This decreases the reliability of such a test, and you should, generally, avoid resorting to this approach.

I do recommend you research Firebase, since major SDK providers often have guidelines on mocking their API. Often such a guidance would include using a dedicated third-party package authored by the SDK provider that allows mocking their internal resources.